# Front end stack for a webapp featuring 'drag n drop'

Tags: drag-and-drop, frontend

I am returning to web development after many years. I did web development before jQuery came along.

Now I see a lot of frameworks to choose from. I see web frameworks (aurelia, ember etc) and then web design frameworks (bootstrap, foundation etc).

My task at hand is too narrow down the technology options for a web app which will provide a certain drag and drop user interface to build workflows.

For drag n drop I have seen, not used, dragulla and interact.js

But not having a hands on experience I am in a confused state. The only certain thing at the moment is the backend which is going to be Django.

Can you please provide some guidance here? My main concern is the ability of doing a smooth drag and drop experience. I would also like to save the state of the flow which is designed by dropping the objects on the canvas, to keep the visual representation of the workflow.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

A simple and basic drag and drop functionality is provided by [jquery ui draggable](https://jqueryui.com/draggable/#sortable).

You can see how simple it is to implement:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Draggable + Sortable</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  ul { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; margin-bottom: 10px; }
  li { margin: 5px; padding: 5px; width: 150px; }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable" ).sortable({
      revert: true
    });
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
      connectToSortable: "#sortable",
      helper: "clone",
      revert: "invalid"
    });
    $( "ul, li" ).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<ul>
  <li id="draggable" class="ui-state-highlight">Drag me down</li>
</ul>

<ul id="sortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>


</body>
</html>
```